# Can PiVPN ping the client first to establish VPN connection?

Tags: pi-2

I am trying to setup a PiVPN on my home network. I installed it on my Raspberry Pi 2B and the server seems to be working fine on the Pi. But if I try to login from my phone, I get the 'Server Poll time out' error. After checking it on the OpenVPN website, it seems to be an issue with the client not able to ping/contact the server.
I checked the port forwarding on the router, and it seeems to be setup fine. But it still isn't able to connect to it.

Now after some research I got to know, that usually on home internet connections the ports are usually blocked. Hence I assume this could be the issue. But I was then curious that how do I get internet if ports are blocked and someone answered that if the connection starts from within the firewall, then the response is allowed back even if ports are blocked. It is a problem if an external source is trying to establish a connection first.

I assume this is the issue with my PiVPN. 
Hence my question can I somehow make my server ping my client to overcome the port blocking issue?
I can create a seperate profile for each device. And also create Dynamic DNS to establish the IP for each client device.

I hope this made sense. I really wish someone can answer this question.
Thank you.

Comment: No. From your description it sounds like you need to configure port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Hi Mark.. I've done the port forwarding in the router.. sadly I don't know how to confirm if the port forwarding is the issue.. one thing I know for sure is that the port 1194 udp is blocked.. I tried checking the status on many websites that let u check port status and they all showed it is blocked.. hence my question, can server contact client first to overcome the blocked port problem??

Comment: No, you can't, that's not how it works. If the port is showing as closed, it isn't forwarded to anywhere. I quickly googled "how to tell if a port is forwarded" and it looked like perhaps there was some useful stuff to help you. I'm afraid I don't have time to get into it, perhaps someone else does, just trying to point you in the right direction.